# URL rewriting: conflicting rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do three things with my URL rewriting:

1. remove .php file extensions
2. have my post URLs look like this: mydomain.co.uk/resources/example-post The default is mydomain.co.uk/resources/post.php?s=example-post
3. have my category archive URLS look like this: mydomain.co.uk/resources/category/example-category The default is mydomain.co.uk/resources/archive.php?cat=example-category

This is what I have in my .htaccess file at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^resources/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /resources/post.php?s=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^resources/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ /resources/archive.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^resources/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /resources/archive.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

It's doing the first two things. But not the third.

If I remove

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Then it does the third things, but not the first two.

Any ideas what's going? How do I get it do all three things at once?

Comment: You are doing it the from way. You should always call your "final" url then rewrite it to your php script. ie. mydomain.co.uk/resources/category/example-category transforms into mydomain.co.uk/resources/archive.php?cat=example-category not the otherway around.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I'm not very good with URL rewriting.

Comment: Do it the other way around. Call the page mydomain.co.uk/resources/category/example-category instead of calling mydomain.co.uk/resources/archive.php?cat=example-category then rewrite to mydomain.co.uk/resources/archive.php?cat=example-category.

Comment: Tried swapping them round. But it didn't work.I might have written the wrong thing in my original question. I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

Just needed to swap the order around, I now have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^resources/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ /resources/archive.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^resources/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /resources/archive.php?cat=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^resources/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /resources/post.php?s=$1 [L]
```

It's working fine.